# How to Reproject GeoJSON without crs property to WGS84 (to use React Leaflet)

Tags: geojson, react-leaflet, map-projections, wgs84, epsg

(Please help I've been struggling with the same problem for more than three days...)

I got GeoJSON file from National Statistical Office, which means it's official data- and the coordinates in this file look like this- :

```
[959394.1770449197,1948599.8772112513], 
... ,
[1140386.5164449196,1684523.5489112514],
```

It's a GeoJSON object without a member named "crs", and as you can see, it's not using the WGS84 datum. Seems like it's coordinates to draw polygons, which are the shape of each district. I assume that there is no problem with data structure.

I tried to create map using this file with React Leaflet, but failed continuously. To find out if it's the problem of GeoJSON that I'm using, I used other GeoJSON files and it worked fine(meaning that interactive map was created on web) - By comparing the GeoJSON files, I found out that coordinates **should be in WGS84** if I want to work with leaflet. So I tried to transform GeoJSON to WGS84 using [reproject](https://github.com/perliedman/reproject). In my react app project, I installed `reproject`, `epsg` and put the code below:

```js
import * as mapData from '../data/sigunguWithPopGeo.json'
import { toWgs84 } from 'reproject'
import 'epsg'

let epsg = require('epsg');
toWgs84(mapData, undefined, epsg);
```

And the error was returned:

```js
Error: Unable to detect CRS, GeoJSON has no "crs" property.
```

Thanks for reading this long intro - Finally here is my question.
**Is there any way to reproject GeoJSON without "crs" property to WGS84?** I also tried [making the coordinates WGS84 with mapshaper.org](https://help.flourish.studio/article/67-how-to-make-your-coordinates-wgs84-with-mapshaper-org). Again, I got the error caused by undefined coordinate system of GeoJSON file:
`Unable to project -- source coordinate system is unknown`

Should I consider adding crs property to GeoJSON? It's my very first time to create the interactive map using GeoJSON with React-leaflet, so any kind of advice from people who experienced similar projects would really help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, solved the problem by myself..!
Instead of keep looking for the methods to convert GeoJSON with undefined coordinate system to WGS84, I visited National Statistical Office's website to figure out the code of coordinate system that was used in src data - which was EPSG 5179. Then I converted GeoJSON file from EPSG 5179 to EPSG 4326(WGS84) on [MyGeoData Converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/). Before downloading the converted data, I checked on the map to see if the coordinates of data was successfully converted to proper lat, lng values. Hope this solution helps who are struggling with similar problems..‍